# Potential Bug of Floating Point Notation in an Integrated Radical

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica version 13.2, tested on MacOS and Windows.

I recently stumbled into what I think is to be a bug with symbolic integration with radicals. Upon testing, I found some cases that I feel exemplify this. Using `esc dintt esc` to form the integral, consider the double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-y^{2}}}\sqrt{16-x^{2}-y^{2}}\ dx\ dy$$

You get an output of $\frac{32 \pi}{3}$. But now simply add a period inside either radical (add `0.`, make `16` into `16.`, etc) and the get new double integral:

$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-y^{2}}}\sqrt{16.-x^{2}-y^{2}}\ dx\ dy$$

Mathematica returns `-33.5103`; a negative number. It gets weirder if you take the sum of these two integrals. Take the following sum:

$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-y^{2}}}\sqrt{16-x^{2}-y^{2}}\ dx\ dy \ + \ \int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-y^{2}}}\sqrt{16.-x^{2}-y^{2}}\ dx\ dy$$

Mathematica returns `-7.10543x10^-15`. Finally, let's add decimals in seemingly random places outside the radicals. Take the following:

$$\int_{0.}^{4.}\int_{0.}^{\sqrt{16-y^{2}}}\left( 0.+ \sqrt{16-x^{2}-y^{2}}\right)\ dx\ dy$$

Mathematica returns `33.5103-3.55271x10^-15 i`; a complex number. Again, this is only when symbolic integration is used. The `Integrate[]` command does not exhibit this behavior.

Is this a bug? If so, is it well known?

[image: Screenshot of code]

EDIT: I didn't previously include working code when using the `Integrate[]` command. The only difference made was using the command opposed to symbolic integrals. Here that is:

[image]

Comment: Although $\TeX$ formulas are pleasing to the eye, please edit your question and include at the end the corresponding Mathematica code for your integrals.

Comment: I've always considered (since V1) `Integrate` to be an exact solver that isn't reliable on inexact input. Introduce machine precision, and `Integrate` is not set up to use numerically stable algebraic operations. If there's a problem with exact input, then that's a different matter. — I don't see a difference between the dintt input and `Integrate[0. + Sqrt[16 - x^2 - y^2], {y, 0., 4.}, {x, 0., Sqrt[16 - y^2]}]`

Comment: @Domen One problem with posting code in this case is that the Q contains a claim that the "2D" input (with `esc dintt esc`) is different than the corresponding input form. (But I don't think the OP used the equivalent input form when testing `Integrate[]`. I think there was a difference that was overlooked.)

Comment: They probably should show their working `Integrate[]` code, tho'

Comment: Bottom line, `Rationalize` the integrand when using `Integrate` or use `NIntegrate` with inexact input (may also need to specify `WorkingPrecision` to switch from machine precision to arbitrary-precision)

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: FWIW Version 12.1 has the same behavior.  Version 8 does all the above calculations correctly or at least gets the results one would expect.

Comment: "But now simply add a period inside either radical" Why???

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I wish I knew, otherwise I wouldn't be publicizing this bug.

Comment: You are not supposed to use float numbers in symbolic calculations.